# Do I need InfoPath installed to open an External Item Picker in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-infopath

I have a DOCX document, which has an External Item Picker.
To open the list of the Item Picker, does the computer needs InfoPath installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need **InfoPath** AND **Business Connectivity Services Client Components** (only available for Microsoft Office Professional Plus).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would assume any ActiveX control you embed in your document will require the host application installed in order to use.